# Can't type in some fields of the nested state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Am having more than two nested state data to post, each nested section has its own component which handles its submission, but the first section allows one to type in its fields but the rest don't.

**Below is the state:**

```
  this.state = {
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            middleName: '',
            nationality: '',
            gender: '',
            religion: '',
            medical_condition: '',
            deceased: '',
            home_address: '',
            country_of_residence: '',
            city: '',
            dob: '',
            age: 0,
            loading: false,
            education:{
                education_level:"",
                school:"",
                address_of_school:"",
                headteacher:"",
                telephone:""
            },
            guardian:{
                first_name:'',
                middle_name:'',
                last_name:'',
                relationship_to_orphan:'',
                occupation:'',
                monthly_income:0.0,
                employers_name:'',
                work_address:'',
                mobile_no:'',
                physical_location:'',
                comments:''
            },
            parents:{
                religion__of_deceased_father:'',
                religion__of_deceased_mother:'',
                date_of_demise_of_father:'',
                date_of_demise_of_mother:'',
                names_of_mother:'',
                religion_of_mother:'',
                marital_status_of_mother:'',
                occupation_of_mother:'',
                monthly_income:0
            },
            siblings:{
                number_of_brothers:0,
                number_of_sisters:0
            }
        }
```

This is how I handle submission of the **education** object in the state. For this case or section, it works well when I try to type in the fields.

```
export const EducationComponent = ({handleChange,obj}) => (
    <Card s={12}>
        <Row>
            <label className={'label-style'}>Education.</label>
        </Row>
        <Row >
            <Input s={3} label="Education Level" className={'label-sizes'}
                   value={obj.education_level}  onChange={handleChange} name={'education'}/>
            <Input s={3} label="School" className={'label-sizes'}
                   value={obj.school}  onChange={handleChange} name={'school'}/>
            <Input s={3} label="Address of School" className={'label-sizes'}
                   value={obj.address_of_school}  onChange={handleChange} name={'address_of_school'}/>
            <Input s={3} label="Nationality" className={'label-sizes'}
                   value={obj.nationality}  onChange={handleChange} name={'nationality'}/>
            <Input s={3} label="Head Teacher" className={'label-sizes'}
                   value={obj.headteacher}  onChange={handleChange} name={'headteacher'}/>
            <Input s={3} label="Telephone" className={'label-sizes'}
                   value={obj.telephone}  onChange={handleChange} name={'telephone'}/>
        </Row>
    </Card>

)
```

The **guardian** section doesn't allow typing in its fields and I know this is related to the `onChange` method but to ,me it seems fine. AM wondering what could cause this ?

Below is it's component :

```
export const GuardianComponent = ({handleChange,obj}) => (
    <Card s={12}>
        <Row>
            <label className={'label-style'}>Guardian Info.</label>
        </Row>
        <Row >
            <Input s={3} label="First Name" className={'label-sizes'} type={'text'}
                   value={obj.first_name}  onChange={handleChange} name={'first_name'}/>
            <Input s={3} label="Last Name" className={'label-sizes'}
                   value={obj.last_name}  onChange={handleChange} name={'last_name'}/>
            <Input s={3} label="Middle Name" className={'label-sizes'}
                   value={obj.middle_name}  onChange={handleChange} name={'middle_name'}/>
            <Input s={3} label="Relationship to the Orphan" className={'label-sizes'}
                   value={obj.relationship_to_orphan}  onChange={handleChange} name={'relationship_to_orphan'}/>
            <Input s={3} label="Occupation" className={'label-sizes'}
                   value={obj.occupation}  onChange={handleChange} name={'occupation'}/>
            <Input s={3} label="Monthly Income" className={'label-sizes'}
                   value={obj.monthly_income}  onChange={handleChange} name={'monthly_income'}/>
            <Input s={3} label="Employers Name" className={'label-sizes'}
                   value={obj.employers_name}  onChange={handleChange} name={'employers_income'}/>
            <Input s={3} label="Work Address" className={'label-sizes'}
                   value={obj.work_address}  onChange={handleChange} name={'work_address'}/>
            <Input s={3} label="Mobile No." className={'label-sizes'}
                   value={obj.mobile_no}  onChange={handleChange} name={'mobile_no'}/>
            <Input s={3} label="Physical Location" className={'label-sizes'}
                   value={obj.physical_location}  onChange={handleChange} name={'physical_location'} />
            <Input s={3} label="Comments" className={'label-sizes'}
                   value={obj.comments}  onChange={handleChange} name={'comments'}/>
        </Row>
    </Card>

)
```

Let me also share the full **container** class where I call all the ***stateless components*** for typing and submission.

```
class CreatePage extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            middleName: '',
            nationality: '',
            gender: '',
            religion: '',
            medical_condition: '',
            deceased: '',
            home_address: '',
            country_of_residence: '',
            city: '',
            dob: '',
            age: 0,
            loading: false,
            education:{
                education_level:"",
                school:"",
                address_of_school:"",
                headteacher:"",
                telephone:""
            },
            guardian:{
                first_name:'',
                middle_name:'',
                last_name:'',
                relationship_to_orphan:'',
                occupation:'',
                monthly_income:0.0,
                employers_name:'',
                work_address:'',
                mobile_no:'',
                physical_location:'',
                comments:''
            },
            parents:{
                religion__of_deceased_father:'',
                religion__of_deceased_mother:'',
                date_of_demise_of_father:'',
                date_of_demise_of_mother:'',
                names_of_mother:'',
                religion_of_mother:'',
                marital_status_of_mother:'',
                occupation_of_mother:'',
                monthly_income:0
            },
            siblings:{
                number_of_brothers:0,
                number_of_sisters:0
            }
        }
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

    }

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
        let config = {
            headers: {
                "Authorization" : "Bearer " + token
            }
        }

        const data = this.state;

        toast('Data submitted ')

        console.log('check data', data)

        axios.post('http://localhost:8080/orphan', data, config)
            .then(res => console.log('success after submission.',res.data))
            .then(error => console.log(error));

    };

    handleChange = (evt) => {
        this.setState({[evt.target.name]: evt.target.value});
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Row>
                    <StudentComponent
                        handleChange={this.handleChange}
                        obj={this.state}
                    />
                    <EducationComponent
                        handleChange={this.handleChange}
                        obj={this.state.education}/>
                    <GuardianComponent
                        handleChange={this.handleChange}
                        obj={this.state.guardian}/>
                    <ParentComponent
                        handleChange={this.handleChange}
                        obj={this.state.parents}/>
                    <SiblingComponent
                        handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                        handleChange={this.handleChange}
                        obj={this.state.siblings}/>
                </Row>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

Am wondering why I can type in **education** component **fields** yet it's state it's nested but I can't type in the **guardian** component **fields** and the rest.

How can I structure my `onChange` function?

Comment: Do the education fields work if you make no changes to "education level" and instead first try to type in the other education fields (e.g. "school")?

Comment: What happens when you try to type something in the guardian component? Any errors in the console? Could you sandbox it somewhere? The provided code isn't complete, it misses the Input component, which is a key to understand how your handleChange function is called. Having a working sandbox will speed up the solution a lot. If you're unsure where to put it, try with https://codesandbox.io/s/new . :)

Comment: Hey @RyanCogswell, I have noticed one field called *nationality* under education worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The surprising part isn't that the guardian fields don't work, but that the education fields do. I suspect that the education fields only work if you type something in the "education_level" field first. You have specified its name as "education" instead of "education_level", so the `handleChange` will then replace the entire "education" object in state with a string. After that occurs, `obj.fieldname` would be undefined for all the "education" fields, since `obj` would now be a string. This turns your education fields into uncontrolled components -- the `value` property is no longer controlling what gets displayed so typing works. If you change the field name of "education_level" to be "education_level" instead of "education", I suspect that the education fields will work just like the guardian fields (i.e. they won't work).

In order for this to work, your `handleChange` needs to know about the parent key in state (e.g. "education", "guardian") in addition to the field name.

Your `handleChange` could look more like the following:

```
handleChange = (parentKey, evt) => {
    this.setState({[parentKey]: {...this.state[parentKey], [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value}});
}
```

And then use it like:

```
<GuardianComponent
    handleChange={(event)=> this.handleChange('guardian', event)}
    obj={this.state.guardian}/>
```

I haven't actually tried this out, so I apologize if I made any syntax errors above, but I think the approach should be sound.